# How to downgrade Jinja for Ansible?

Tags: ansible, python, jinja, macos

I'm using Ansible 2.8.0 (`ansible --version` installed by `brew` on macOS) which is using Jinja 2.10.

I've tried to downgrade Jinja to 2.8 via `pip3 install jinja2==2.8`, and I can confirm the right version with `pip3 list`, but Ansible is still using Jinja 2.10 (verified by [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49045145/55075)). It seems it's using different Python's `site-packages` folder.

I'd like to downgrade Jinja due to [a bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/51727), so I'd like to test Ansible using older version of Jinja.

How do I downgrade Jinja used by Ansible, ideally without downgrading Ansible it-self?

---

```
$  ansible --version
ansible 2.8.0
  config file = /Users/kenorb/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/kenorb/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.8.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15) [Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)]
$  pip3 --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
$  brew info ansible
ansible: stable 2.8.0 (bottled), HEAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ansible was installed via Homebrew on macOS, the workaround is to install Ansible using Pip.

```
$ brew remove ansible
$ pip3 install ansible
$  pip3 list | grep -e ansible -e Jinja2
ansible      2.8.0  
Jinja2       2.8    
$  ansible-playbook check_jinja.yaml -v
TASK [jinja_version]
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "msg": "2.8"}
```